# Numbering two sets of equations

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

There are many question and answers already on the subject, but I have not found any suitable one for my request, so I hope you can help me.

I have two quite big systems of equations, one is the log-linearization of the other. I would like numbering of the form:

```
\section{First section}
... (1a)
... (2a)
... (3a)
\section{Second section}
... (1b)
... (2b)
... (3b)
```

where the ellipses stand for equations. As one equation exactly relates to the other, I find this a much better structure in my thesis than simply writing equations (1) to (6). Also, I am not too fixated on the exact notation, so if someone has a better way of doing this, I am eager to here it.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} 
\usepackage{textcomp,mathrsfs,xcolor,float,fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \pagenumbering{arabic}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Equilibrium}

\section{Deflated Equilibrium}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
b=c \\ 
c=d
\end{align}
\section{Log-Lin Equilibrium}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
b=c \\
c=d
\end{align}

\end{document}}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}\alph{section}}` for example? But does allow for 26 sections only, I don't know if this will be enough  then ;-)

Comment: Sadly, it is not. :-) Also, subequations connects equations (1) to (3) and (4) to (6). I am looking for a way to connect (1) and (4), (2) and (5), and (3) and (6)

Comment: We need more information on this, a compilable document. I am thinking about an idea with coupled counters but this is only a raw idea

Comment: I added a MWE, hope that helps!

Comment: Are you using `equation` only? No `align` environment with more than one line such that those are numbered as well? And how do you settle the connection between, say `1a` and  `1b`-- is this just the order of equations?

Comment: Yes, I also use blocks of `align` within the sections.  And the order and number of equations is identical in both sections.

Comment: The manual repetition of equations is error prone with respect to the ordering. Are the align/equation environments in fact repetitions, i.e. the content is the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing the instructions

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}\alph{section}}
```

should let you achieve your formatting objective. That said, you may want to think about what your readers are supposed to learn when they encounter equations numbered, say, "(1a)" in chapters 1, 2, and 3...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \numberwithin macro and 'align' env.
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % tie `equation` counter to `section` counter
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}\alph{section}}

\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{chapter} % just for this example

\section{Deflated Equilibrium}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
b=c \\ 
c=d
\end{align}

\section{Log-Lin Equilibrium}
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
b=c \\
c=d
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've stolen my proposition :-(

Comment: No! I was playing drama ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - :-)

Comment: Thank you both for valuable help!! The only adjustment I had to made is to add `\arabic{chapter}.` to the `\theequation` command, such that the numbering is consistent with other chapters.

Comment: @Mico: Well, 5 upvotes ;-) I would not have been awarded with this, although I had a similar idea.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I honestly still can't predict with any degree of confidence how many upvotes a given answer will attract. Some answers I'm pretty pleased with myself never receive more than 2 or 3 upvotes, while others I personally find fairly mundane get 5 or even 10 upvotes within the first 24 hours. (Don't ask me how I feel about the current answer...) Do you have similar experiences?